# Linear Equations - How to solve?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be linear spaces and $L : X → Y$ be a linear map.
Say $x1$ and $x2$ are particular solutions of the equations $Lx = y1$ and $Lx = y2$, respectively,
while $z ≠ 0$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $Lz=0$.

What's a solution for $Lx=3y1$ ?
What's a solution for $Lx = -5y2$ ?

Comment: You've forgotten the third question: What did you try?

Comment: How do I approach this?  If I could see a simple example I could probably understand how to do this.

Comment: Try a test case: Choose $X$ and $Y$ to be $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $L$ represented by some matrix.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$L x=3y_1\iff Lx=3L x_1=L(3x_1)\iff L(x-3x_1)=0$$
hence $x-3x_1$ is a solution for the homogeneous equation so for  $z\in \ker L$ we have

$$x-3x_1=z\iff x=3x_1+z\in 3x_1+\ker L$$